# How do I correctly format a target time for a countdown?

Tags: python, datetime, countdown

Right now I'm trying to enter a time in 24 hour format and initiate a countdown from the current time to the specified time.

So currently the user is entering a target hour and a target minute. I'm not sure what to do with these values to begin a countdown from now until the specified time.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now() # gets the time now, puts it in now

expiringHour = int(input("What hour does the meter expire? Enter 0-23 "))

if expiringHour < 0:
    print("Error. Enter a correct value")
if expiringHour > 23:
    print("Error. Enter a correct value")

expiringMinute = int(input("What minute does the meter expire? Enter 0-59 "))

if expiringMinute < 0:
    print("Error. Enter a correct value")
if expiringMinute > 59:
    print("Error. Enter a correct value")

print(expiringHour, expiringMinute)
```

Comment: What do you mean by a countdown? Do you want your program to print out the remaining time every second? Do you want to display a dialog box with a clock that displays the remaining time? Or the current time? I think you need to be more specific to get a useful answer.

Comment: Does `strptime` http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime not do what you want?

Comment: I'd like a dialog box with a clock that shows remaining time

Comment: If you would like a simple dialog box, your necessity is bit involved. Check my answer below, for what I did for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you convert the values to a datetime, and then eneter a loop where display the remaining time from now to the expiring minute, and then sleep for a while, and then display it again, until it reaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the correct answer to this involves creating a datetime.datetime object and incrementing the datetime.datetime object till we reach the finish time.

But since you said you wanted a GUI, I had used [python wrapper over xdaliclock](http://phoe6.livejournal.com/100863.html) on Ubuntu to have a countdown timer. Yeah, this is not applicable if you are on a system where xdaliclock is not available.